# RESTful Webservice - getRemoteUser works with GET but not with POST! Why?

Tags: java, post, java-ee-6, cdi, restful-authentication

i have a Stateless Restful Webservice. In this Service I've injected a context:

@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

If i call the Method request.getRemoteUser() in a GET Method it works! But If I call it in a POST Method I get "null" although the Authentification Works.

Can anyone explain that?

Greez Wolfgang

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Path you are POSTing to is not protected by your security constraint - this may lead to this behaviour (depends on settings / Servlet-Container).
If this is not the reason - which Servlet-Container are you using?